# Got the error 1046 when changing the property of a component from a RSL

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got a problem about the RSL. I created a RSL named a.fla, and I created a component which basic class is XXButton.as(written by myself.), I reflected some property for designers to change the button's label, besides, this component's Name and Class are both `"ShareLib_Button"`.

[image]

Then I put the button in B.fla as a import component(checked the "Import for runtime sharing."). And I ignored the "Automatically declare stage instance" in the flash publish setting.

When I just put this component on B's stage, exporting the fla is ok. But when I changed the property which I reflected of the component, I got the error 1046.

```
 "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ShareLib_Button".
```

Does anyone have any ideas about it?

Thanks in advance!

Echo

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have much experience with Runtime Shared Libraries, the error is indicating that it doesn't have access to your library when you compiled `b.fla`.  Try the following:

In your `a.fla` file...

1. Give the Sprite that holds the imported components a binding class
2. Edit the class file, declare the components yourself regardless of whether checked the "Automatically declare stage instances"

In your `b.fla` file...

1. Open the Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Settings dialog box.
2. Click the Library path tab.
3. Add the path to the RSL.
4. Set the default linkage to "Runtime shared library (RSL)"

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.  I tried but failed. And the strange thing is if I didn't change the property, it won't cause this error. I don't know what the special issue of property .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because I tried to access an unknown property. I need to declare an instance name(Because of some reasons, we don't use instance names, I removed this setting, and fill an instance name), it works!

Thanks everyone who cares this.